# Relation between Inverse of two Matrix A and Matrix B, Where A<B ( Positive Definite )

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ and $B$ are two Positive Definite Matrix, Where $ A < B $, What is the relation between there inverse?

Comment: Do you mean $\det(A)<\det(B)$?

Answer (score 1):

By $A < B$, I will assume you mean $B - A$ is a positive definite matrix.  To avoid confusion, I will use $P \succ 0$ and $P \succ Q$ to indicate $P$ and $P - Q$ are positive definitie matrices.

---

In general, for positive definite matrices $A$ and $B$, we have $B \succ A \implies A^{-1} \succ B^{-1}$.

Since $B \succ A \succ 0$, we have $C = B - A \succ 0$. 
Notice
$$B(A^{-1} - B^{-1})B = (A+C)A^{-1}(A+C) - B = A + 2C + CA^{-1}C - B = C + CA^{-1}C$$

Recall positive definite matrices are closed are matrix addition, taking inverse and multiply by same positive definite matrix on both sides. We find

$$A \succ 0 \implies A^{-1} \succ 0 \implies C A^{-1} C \succ 0 \implies C + CA^{-1}C \succ 0$$

This leads to
$$B(A^{-1} - B^{-1})B \succ 0 \implies
A^{-1} - B^{-1} = B^{-1} (B(A^{-1} - B^{-1})B)B^{-1} \succ 0$$